# Run a remote PHP script from an Ethernet-Shield Arduino

Tags: php, web, get, arduino

I have a PHP script on an external web server. If I view `www.example.com/test/myphp.php` in my browser, the server runs the script just fine. Now I want the server to run the script when my Arduino says so, instead of when I view it in my browser. I want the Arduino to remotely trigger the script to run.

I am a complete newbie to servers / php / the web, so any tips would be appreciated, especially with the GET synatx (if that's even the right command?). The Arduino has an ethernet shield and can connect to the server fine. The below code correctly connects, but unlike when I open `www.example.com/test/myphp.php` in my browser, the PHP file doesn't actually run when it's accessed from the Arduino :(

Do you have any suggestions for how I can modify this to get the PHP file to run when my Arduino tells it to?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

char server[] = "www.example.com";    

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192,168,0,177);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server 
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("SERIAL: Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
  }

  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("SERIAL: connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {

     client.print("GET /test/myphp.php");
     client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
     client.println("Host: www.example.com");
     client.println("User-Agent: Arduino");
     client.println("Accept: text/html");
     client.println("Connection: close");
     client.println();

  } 
  else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("SERIAL: connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // if there are incoming bytes available, print them
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the User agent to something like Firefox (e.g. "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:22.0) Gecko/20130405 Firefox/23.0")?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! Yes, I have. I have also tried omitting the field entirely, which is what this person seems to have done: http://spikybear.com/blog/?p=258.

Comment: You can send the Get via telnet (on the pc), to test what the Server accepts. To connect you would use "telnet www.example.com 80" the absolute minimum would be "Get /test/my.php" then two times return, now your script should run. If not the server is more restrictive and you might need to send additional information with your get.

Comment: Good sir, you are MY HERO! That wasn't the error but what you said (the server might be more restrictive) led me to it!!! The problem was that I had forgotten to register my devices MAC address with my school's wifi, it was working on my computer but not on the uC because the school had it blocked.

Comment: is it working perfect for u now? what's the update?! i was about to suggest adding http://

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this but.. i think that you should include this piece of code inside the loop.
Not Outside it.

```
 if (client.connect(server, 80)) {

     client.print("GET /test/myphp.php");
     client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
     client.println("Host: www.example.com");
     client.println("User-Agent: Arduino");
     client.println("Accept: text/html");
     client.println("Connection: close");
     client.println();
}
```